# Splunk Rex: Extracting fields of a string to a value

Tags: splunk, splunk-query, splunk-formula, rex, splunk-sum

I'm a newbie to SPlunk trying to do some dashboards and need help in extracting fields of a particular variable

Here in my case i want to extract only KB_List":"KB000119050,KB000119026,KB000119036" values to a column

```
Expected output:

KB_List
KB000119050,KB000119026,KB000119036
```

i have tried:

```
| rex field=_raw "\*"KB_List":(?<KB_List>\d+)\*"
```

highlighted the part below in the log

> svc_log_ERROR","Impact":4.0,"CategoryId":"94296c474f356a0009019ffd0210c738","hasKBList":"true","lastNumOfAlerts":1,"splunkURL":false,"impactedInstances":"","highestSeverity":"Minor","Source":"hsym-plyfss01","reqEmail":"true","AlertGroup":"TIBCOP","reqPage":"","KB_List":"KB000119050,KB000119026,KB000119036","reqTicket":"true","autoTicket":true,"SupportGroup":"TESTPP","Environment":"UAT","Urgency":4.0,"AssetId":"AST000000000159689","LiveSupportGroup":"TESTPP","sentPageTo":"TESTPP"},"Notification":{"":{"requestId":"532938335"}},"":

Answer (score 2):

```
rex field=_raw "KB_List\":\"(?<KB_List>[^\"])\""
```

This regular expression will look for anything that begins with `KB_List":"`, the capture everything except a `"`.

In your example, you are only capturing digits (`\d+`), whereas the contents in the KB_List field also contain characters ("KB" and ",")

Comment: THank you @Simon Duff but i couldn't get any output with above? any pointers –

Answer (score 2):

Alas:

I figured out by looking into so many articles:

```
| rex "KB_List\":\"(?<KB_Listed>[^\"]+)" | table KB_Listed
```

Comment: Not that it makes a *great* deal of difference, but this regex is ever so slightly more efficient: `KB_List[^K]+(?<kblist>[^\"]+)`